# Convert chrono::duration to string or C string

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, c++-chrono

I'm trying to make a table (a 9 by 11 array) that stores the amount of time taken by a function by several sorting functions.

I think I want the table to be a string.  I currently cannot solve how to convert `chrono` to `string` and haven't been able to find any resources online.

Do I need to abandon the string typing for the table, or is there a way to store these time differences in a string?

```
for (int i = 0; i<8;i++) // sort 8 different arrays
{ 
    start = chrono::system_clock::now(); 
    //Sort Array Here
    end = chrono::system_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    table[1][i] = string(elapsed_seconds)   // error: no matching conversion for functional style cast
}
```

Comment: Don't you want `elapsed_seconds.count()`? And btw; `std::string` doesn' have a constructor that does the conversion you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to stream into a `std::ostringstream`, and then retrieve the string from that stream.

To stream a `chrono::duration` you could use its `.count()` member function, and then you might want to add units (e.g. `ns` or whatever the unit is).

This free, header-only, open-source library:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/chrono_io.html makes it easier to stream a `duration` by automatically appending the units for you.

For example:

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date;
    ostringstream out;
    auto t0 = chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto t1 = chrono::system_clock::now();
    out << t1 - t0;
    string s = out.str();
    cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Just output for me:

```
0µs
```

Without [`"chrono_io.h"`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/chrono_io.html) it looks more like:

```
    out << chrono::duration<double>(t1 - t0).count() << 's';
```

There's also the `to_string` family that could be used:

```
    string s = to_string(chrono::duration<double>(t1 - t0).count()) + 's';
```

There is no `to_string` that goes directly from a `chrono::duration` however.  You have to "escape" out with `.count()` and then add units (if desired).

---

### Update

C++20 brings the functionality of `"chrono_io.h"` straight into `<chrono>`.  So no longer a need for the free open-source library.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `chrono::duration_cast` like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    //Sort Array Here
    end = chrono::system_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    auto x = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(elapsed_seconds);

    //to_string
    string result = to_string(x.count());

    cout <<  result;
}
```

**result:**

**- In seconds:**

0 seconds

**- In µs:**

```
auto x = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(elapsed_seconds);
```

**result:**

535971µs

Comment: Where is `to_string`from?

Comment: from std: https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/, std::to_string