# chrono type to string c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I am trying to format the time into hh::mm::ss then put it in a wide-string-stream. The code is as follows.

```
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        std::chrono::steady_clock::duration time_elapsed = end - start;

        std::chrono::hh_mm_ss formatted {std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (time_elapsed)};
```

`start` is in the constructor of the class. using the `<<` stream operators do not work and i do not see any way to convert this type to a string.
My question is how can i convert `formatted` to a string (c style, wstring, or normal string)?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: msvc, on vs 2019

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: oops i guess i shouldve clarified, there was no error, i just needed a way to convert to string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert chrono::duration to string or C string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866524/convert-chronoduration-to-string-or-c-string)

Comment: no, putting the var in a string stream then calling str() then converting to c str worked for me which is the answer thats marked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me in `MSVC`.
As of 2021-08-12 I had to use the `/std:c++latest` switch with Visual Studio version `16.11.2` in order for this solution to work.

```
const auto start{ std::chrono::steady_clock::now( ) };
std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds{ 1000 } );
const auto end{ std::chrono::steady_clock::now( ) };

const auto elapsed{ end - start };

std::chrono::hh_mm_ss formatted{ 
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( elapsed ) };

std::cout << formatted << '\n';

// Or
std::stringstream ss{ };
ss << formatted;

std::cout << ss.str( ) << '\n';
```

Comment: What compiler flags did you use? Using `/std:c++20` wasn't sufficient for msvc 19.latest here: https://godbolt.org/z/GeTv9do46 it only worked with `/std:c++latest` (maybe that's part of the OP's problem)

Comment: yes i was using c++20, switching to c++latest i was able to get it to work. Is this a going-forward solution?

Comment: Depends *exactly* what version of 2019 you're using.  If you're on 16.11.x, then c++20 *should* work (didn't try it yet myself), but if below, you'll need `latest`

Comment: @noah Sorry for the late response. Yes I was using `latest` with VS version `16.11.2`. If I use the `/std:c++20` switch then this solution does not work (as you described in your original question).  I updated my answer with that information.