# How to get the value of a set TimePicker field programmatically

Tags: winui-3, c++-winrt

I created a WinUI 3 project. I have a timepicker field and it has the value selectedtime="11:11". I can't figure out how to get its value in code

Tried like this
MainWindows.xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TimePicker x:Name="Control2" ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" Header="24 hour clock" SelectedTime="11:11" />
    <Button  x:Name="myButton" Content="Click" Click="myButton_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindows.xaml.cpp

```
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        auto selectedTime = Control2().SelectedTime();
        auto nameTimePicker = Control2().Name(); // get property value x:Name = Control2
        myButton().Content(box_value(selectedTime));
        // This closes the program
        // selectedTime.GetString().c_str()
    }
```

Button text `Windows.Foundation.IReference<Windows.Foundation.TimeSpan>`

Can you please tell me how I can also get the text time SelectedTime = "11:11"? as I received x:Name="Control2".

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.timespan.duration *TimeSpan is a specialization of std::chrono::duration* and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866524/convert-chronoduration-to-string-or-c-string for example

Comment: This example shows how to set, and I need to get the value of the timepicker, namely its fields selectedtime="11:11"

Comment: TimePicker has SelectedTime or Time, with C++/WinRT they are bound as `std::chrono::duration`. There's nothing more with this language.

Comment: So the actual question here is how to convert a `std::chrono::duration` into a textual representation?

Comment: @IInspectable 
not how to convert, but how to get the time 11:11, into the text and insert it into the button (the name of the button will be 11:11), from the SelectedTime = "11:11" field. Just like I got the TimePicker's name (Control2().Name())

Comment: So, that's a *"yes"*, even though you believe the problem to be something else. `Control2().Name()` returns a (value compatible with) `HSTRING`. That can be used as the source to set a `Button`'s `Content` property. The same does not apply for a `std::chrono::duration` (or `TimeSpan`). You'll have to convert that to a textual representation first. That's going to involve a concept called "locale", which could be inferred in more than one way. You'll have to be explicit about that conversion, meaning that you have to write code.

Comment: @IInspectable 
Could you show an example of how you can convert Control2().SelectedTime to text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use std::format with std::formatter<std::chrono::duration>.

```
auto selectedTime = Control2().SelectedTime().Value();
auto nameTimePicker = Control2().Name(); // get property value x:Name = Control2
std::string s = std::format("{:%R}", selectedTime);//"C" locale
myButton().Content(box_value(winrt::to_hstring(s)));
```

[image]

Other information: [winrt::hstring functions and operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/strings#winrthstring-functions-and-operators).